# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body user_id: Value is not a snowflake

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my leaderboard script to work, but I keep encountering this error.

This only started after I started using a command handler:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "leaderboard",
    aliases: ['lb'],
    description: "leaderboard",
    async run (Discord, client, message, member, args, Levels) {
      const rawLeaderboard = await Levels.fetchLeaderboard(message.guild.id, 10);
      if (rawLeaderboard.length < 1) return message.reply("Nobody's in leaderboard yet.");
      const leaderboard = await Levels.computeLeaderboard(client, rawLeaderboard, true);
      const lb = leaderboard.map(e => `${e.position}. 
             ${e.username}#${e.discriminator}\nLevel: 
             ${e.level}\nXP: ${e.xp.toLocaleString()}`);
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setColor("WHITE")
       .setTitle("LEADERBOARD")
       .setDescription(lb.join("\n\n"))
      message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
   }
}
```

ERROR:

> \node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
> throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
> ^
>
> DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body user_id: Value
> "<@My ID>" is not snowflake.
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\ME\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bots\Test
> Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\ME\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bots\Test
> Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
> at async UserManager.fetch (C:\Users\ME\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bots\Test
> Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\UserManager.js:93:18)
> at async Function.computeLeaderboard (C:\Users\ME\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bots\Test
> Bot\node_modules\discord-xp\index.js:271:22)
> at async Object.run (C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bots\Test Bot\commands\leaderboard.js:15:29) {   method: 'get',
> path: '/users/<@my id>',   code: 50035,   httpStatus:
> 400,   requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] } }

Comment: Are you sure the error is here? It looks like you don't store the users as snowflakes.

Comment: This is almost the exact same code I was using before, but it stopped working as soon as I switched over to using a command handler

Comment: Then how do you explain that the error says `Value "<@My ID>" is not snowflake` and tries to fetch from the endpoint `/users/<@my id>`? There is nothing wrong with this part of the code. But if you check the [source code](https://github.com/MrAugu/discord-xp/blob/78f6d1d31b452e9db3efc628ac34f6a3c752bd51/index.js#L271) you can see that it tries to fetch `key.userID` and this error means that there is at least one item in `rawLeaderboard ` where the `userID` is not a snowflake. So how do you create the leaderboard?

Comment: Sorry I am not the most proficient coder, and please let me know if this is not the answer you're looking for, but the information of the users is stored in mongodb

Comment: Can you check how the user ids are stored in mongoDB? Like `<@806954761383182377>` or like `806954761383182377`? It looks like it should be stored as the second one.

Comment: It's stored as 806954761383182377

Comment: Is it stored as a string or a number?

Comment: It's stored as a string

Comment: this same exact code was working before, the only thing that changed was me moving the command to call for the leaderboard from "main.js" to a guild event handler